# pagination in woocommerce order history page

Tags: customization, pagination, woocommerce-offtopic

Please help me to add pagination in my order history page. Pagination should work like WooCommerce products page.

Here is my code:

```
<?php $customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => '20',
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
) ) );
if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_title', __( 'Order History', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></h2>

    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="order-number"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-date"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-status"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-total"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-actions">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody><?php
            foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
                $order      = wc_get_order();
                $order->populate( $customer_order );
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count();

                ?><tr class="order">
                    <td class="order-number" data-title="<?php _e( 'Order Number', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $order->get_view_order_url(); ?>">
                            #<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-date" data-title="<?php _e( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <time datetime="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-status" data-title="<?php _e( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap;">
                        <?php echo wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-total" data-title="<?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s for %s item', '%s for %s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-actions">
                        <?php
                            $actions = array();

                            if ( in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                $actions['pay'] = array(
                                    'url'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                                    'name' => __( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' )
                                );
                            }

                            if ( in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                $actions['cancel'] = array(
                                    'url'  => $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ),
                                    'name' => __( 'Cancel', 'woocommerce' )
                                );
                            }

                            $actions['view'] = array(
                                'url'  => $order->get_view_order_url(),
                                'name' => __( 'View', 'woocommerce' )
                            );

                            $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order );

                            if ($actions) {
                                foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
                                    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="view_order_dtls button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr><?php
            }

        ?></tbody>

    </table>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What *specific* problem are you having? What have you tried? Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't already.

Comment: hi pat i need to display orders placed by the customers as 10 orders per page using woocommerce plugin (wordpress) i can't add pagination for orders page.

Answer (score 3):

I have added pagination in order history page and it is working.
Replace below code above loop

```
$customer_orders1 = get_posts(apply_filters('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value' => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type' => wc_get_order_types('view-orders'),
    'post_status' => array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses())
)));
$total_records = count($customer_orders1);
$posts_per_page = 20;
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $posts_per_page);
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$customer_orders = get_posts(array(
    'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value' => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type' => wc_get_order_types('view-orders'),
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses())
));
```

and after loop completed add pagination

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'base' => '%_%',
        'format' => '?page=%#%',
        'total' => $total_pages,
        'current' => $paged,
        'show_all' => False,
        'end_size' => 5,
        'mid_size' => 5,
        'prev_next' => True,
        'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Previous'),
        'next_text' => __('Next &raquo;'),
        'type' => 'plain',
        'add_args' => False,
        'add_fragment' => ''
    );
    echo paginate_links($args);
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: On the latest version of WooCommerce, I had to change 2 things: 1. `'base' => @add_query_arg('?page', '%#%'),` and 2. `'format' => '?page=%#%'` - This was because when clicking page 1, this would just reload the 2nd page. A page 1 query wasn't working until I made this change.

Comment: @Khushbu Padalia
What about for "View All"?